# Flutter Audio file to text

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-file

How can I get the sound I recorded in a file in flutter as a string(text) every word of it?
as an example, he will say hello world in the audio file.How can I get this as a string
String getText = "hello world";
i know about google's speech-to-text product, but it seems too expensive, isn't there another way for me to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Try this package

[google_speech: ^2.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_speech)

To convert audio to text use the code below

```
Future<List<int>> _getAudioContent(String name) async {
   final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   final path = directory.path + '/$name';
   return File(path).readAsBytesSync().toList();
 }

final audio = await _getAudioContent('test.wav');

final response = await speechToText.recognize(config, audio);


print(response);
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but that's not what I wanted.I won't speak, I need the words in an audio file I received

Comment: thank you for your help, but as I mentioned at the top, the cost of that package exceeds me.I'm looking for if there is a free way

Comment: @IstakozNecmi Build your own API. Get a pre-trained AI from tf hub or huggingface, then deploy with Flask or Django. It may take a lot of effort